# Need help-Method specific validation in struts 2

Tags: java, validation, struts2

I am creating a sample application with two methods(execute,addEmployee) in a same action class(Employee.java). I need to validate some common fields in both the methods and I have some method specific validations.
My Employee.java code is:

```
public class Employee extends ActionSupport{
   public String execute() 
   {
       return SUCCESS;
   }

   public String addEmployee()
   {
       return SUCCESS;
   }
}
```

And validation files:

Employee-validation.xml code to validate required field validations for name and age fields.

**Employee-execute-validation.xml**

```
 <field name="age">
    <field-validator type="int">
    <param name="min">10</param>
    <param name="max">40</param>
    <message>Age must be in between 10 and 40</message>
    </field-validator>
    </field>
```

**Employee-addEmployee-validation.xml**

```
 <field name="gender">
    <field-validator type="int">
    <param name="min">1</param>
    <message>Please select a value</message>
    </field-validator>
    </field>
```

But while running, only rules defined in Employee-validation.xml works.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Validation could be defined per action aliases not per methods.

```
<actionClass>-<actionAlias>-validation.xml
```

The `actionAlias` here refers to the action name in configuration not method in action class.

Comment: Example of what? If you have `Employee-addEmployee-validation.xml` file that means your action name in configuration must be `addEmployee`.

Answer (score 0):

your are validating at Action level so place your {youractionfile}-validation.xml in the same package of your Action Class. There can be one validation for one Action class.
Try this!!

> Employee-validation.xml

```
<validators>
<field name="age">
    <field-validator type="int">
    <param name="min">10</param>
    <param name="max">40</param>
    <message>Age must be in between 10 and 40</message>
    </field-validator>
    </field> 
<field name="gender">
    <field-validator type="int">
    <param name="min">1</param>
    <message>Please select a value</message>
    </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

Comment: yes.. I placed Employee-validation file also in the same package. Emplyee-validation.xml code is to have required field validators for name and age fields alone. @divyadharathi

Comment: for one action class one validation has to be there.

Comment: @divyabharathi: It could be more than one validation file for single action.